# Choosing between RAM frequency and timings

Tags: memory, memory-timings

I have 2 sets of SAMSUNG 2GB DDR3 RAM

1: 2 x 2GB 2Rx8 PC3-8500S-07-10-F2

2: 2 x 2GB 2Rx8 PC3-10600S-09-10-F2

There 2 main differences: (8500S vs 10600S) and (07 vs 09)

Which set is better to install in my laptop?

Thank you.

Comment: Generally speaking, questions of "which is better" lend themselves to opinion-based answers. Can you [edit] your question, rephrasing it to ask for a more objective criteria on which to base an answer?

Answer (score 2):

If your laptop is able to utilize the 10600 one (i.e. not running it throttled), then pick those. If it supports only up to 8500 (or even less); pick the one with the better timings.

Comment: How do I know if it's capable or not? it's a 13,3" Toshiba Satellite T130. and in the specs in many sites they show it has 2GB + 1GB DDR3 800MHz. While here I have it with 4GB and it recognizes them well.

Comment: Hm... [According to Toshiba](http://www.toshiba.eu/discontinued-products/satellite-t130-10g/) it supports "DDR3 800 MHz", which is almost as vague as it can get. So it either supports up to PC3-6400 (2 * 400 MHz) or up to PC3-12800 (2 * 800 MHz). I assume the first, so pick the PC3-8500 due to lower timings. If you'd like to make extra sure, grab a tool such as [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and compare the timings/frequency displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Faster RAM is better in general. If the frequencies are the same, lower timings are preferred, but unless you're an enthusiast, you won't see much difference day-to-day.